# How do you get debugging symbols working in linux perf tool inside Docker containers?

Tags: linux, docker, linux-kernel, perf

I am using Docker containers based on the "ubuntu" tag and cannot get linux perf tool to display debugging symbols.

Here is what I'm doing to demonstrate the problem.

First I start a container, here with an interactive shell.

```
$ docker run -t -i ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

Then from the container prompt I install linux perf tool.

```
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install -y linux-tools-common linux-tools-generic linux-tools-`uname -r`
```

I can now use the `perf` tool. My kernel is `3.16.0-77-generic`.

Now I'll install `gcc`, compile a test program, and try to run it under `perf record`.

```
$ apt-get install -y gcc
```

I paste in the test program into `test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int function(int i) {
    int j;
    for(j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    int i;
    for(i = 2; i < 100000; i++) {
        if(function(i)) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
}
```

Then compile, run, and report:

```
$ gcc -g -O0 test.c && perf record ./a.out && perf report
```

The output looks something like this:

```
  72.38%  a.out  a.out              [.] 0x0000000000000544
   8.37%  a.out  a.out              [.] 0x000000000000055a
   8.30%  a.out  a.out              [.] 0x000000000000053d
   7.81%  a.out  a.out              [.] 0x0000000000000551
   0.40%  a.out  a.out              [.] 0x0000000000000540
```

This does not have symbols, even though the executable does have symbol information.

Doing the same general steps outside the container works fine, and shows something like this:

```
96.96%  a.out  a.out             [.] function 
0.35%  a.out  libc-2.19.so       [.] _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0.14%  a.out  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] update_curr
0.12%  a.out  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] update_cfs_shares
0.11%  a.out  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] _raw_spin_lock_irqsave
```

In the host system I have already turned on kernel symbols by becoming root and doing:

```
$ echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict
```

How do I get the containerized version to work properly and show debugging symbols?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Running the container with `-v /:/host` flag and running `perf report` in the container with `--symfs /host` flag fixes it:

```
 96.59%  a.out  a.out              [.] function
  2.93%  a.out  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] 0xffffffff8105144a
  0.13%  a.out  [nvidia]           [k] 0x00000000002eda57
  0.11%  a.out  libc-2.19.so       [.] vfprintf
  0.11%  a.out  libc-2.19.so       [.] 0x0000000000049980
  0.09%  a.out  a.out              [.] main
  0.02%  a.out  libc-2.19.so       [.] _IO_file_write
  0.02%  a.out  libc-2.19.so       [.] write
```

Part of the reason why it doesn't work as is? The output from `perf script` sort of sheds some light on this:

```
...
           a.out    24 3374818.880960: cycles:  ffffffff81141140 __perf_event__output_id_sample ([kernel.kallsyms])
           a.out    24 3374818.881012: cycles:  ffffffff817319fd _raw_spin_lock_irqsave ([kernel.kallsyms])
           a.out    24 3374818.882217: cycles:  ffffffff8109aba3 ttwu_do_activate.constprop.75 ([kernel.kallsyms])
           a.out    24 3374818.884071: cycles:            40053d [unknown] (/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/9bd2d4389cf7ad185405245b1f5c7d24d461bd565757880bfb4f970d3f4f7915/a.out)
           a.out    24 3374818.885329: cycles:            400544 [unknown] (/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/9bd2d4389cf7ad185405245b1f5c7d24d461bd565757880bfb4f970d3f4f7915/a.out)
...
```

Note the `/var/lib/docker/aufs` path.  That's from the host so it won't exist in the container and you need to help `perf report` to locate it.  This likely happens because the mmap events are tracked by perf outside of any cgroup and perf does not attempt to remap the paths.

Another option is to run perf host-side, like `sudo perf record -a docker run -ti <container name>`.  But the collection has to be system-wide here (the `-a` flag) as containers are spawned by docker daemon process which is not in the process hierarchy of the docker client tool we run here.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly it.
To add to the solution, in order to get kernel symbols you also need to add:
`--kallsyms=/proc/kallsyms`.

Comment: In case it helps anyone else: an even simpler way is to call `docker run` with `-v /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker`, that makes it so `perf` does not require any special arguments to resolve symbols correctly.

Answer (score 8):

Another way that doesn't require changing how you run the container (so you can profile an already running process) is to mount container's root on host using bindfs:

```
bindfs /proc/$(docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} $CONTAINER_ID)/root /foo
```

Then run perf report as `perf report --symfs /foo`

You'll have to run `perf record` system wide, but you can restrict it to only collect events for the specific container:

```
perf record -g -a -F 100 -e cpu-clock -G docker/$(docker inspect --format {{.Id}} $CONTAINER_ID) sleep 90
```

Comment: The bindfs `/proc/$(docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} $CONTAINER_ID)/root /foo` command resulting in `/foo` point to host file system (host `root` folder). Why? Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem on RHEL; note that Eduardo has already raised a (unanswered) question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565598/bindfs-doesnt-work-for-folder-inside-proc

Comment: The question now has [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52740682/1069467) and the issue is fixed in bindfs 1.13.10

Comment: looks like this method doesn't work with containerd

Comment: @MinZhou can confirm. have you found any other way for containerd?